# Derivative of a matrix function including cross and dot products

Tags: derivatives, matrix-calculus

I have three $3D$ vectors ($3\times 1$ matrix) $\vec a$, $\vec b$ and $\vec t$   and also a $3\times 3$ matrix $M$. 
If $f$ is define as below:
$$f=\frac{\left\lVert M\vec a \times (\vec b-\vec t) \right\rVert_2}{M\vec a.(\vec b-\vec t)}$$

what is the the partial derivatives of $f$ wrt $t$ and $M$, i.e. $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} $ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial M} $?

Note:

1) $\left\lVert ... \right\rVert_2$ stands for norm-2 (magnitude of the    vector)

2) "." stands for inner (dot) product

3) "$\times$" stands for cross product

4) $M\vec a$ is a conventional matrix product

Answer (score 1):

Consider this scalar function of two vectors $(y,z)$, where the first vector $(y)$ is a constant.
$$\eqalign{
 \phi &= \frac{\|y\times z\|^2}{(y:z)^2} \cr
 &= \frac{(z:z)(y:y)-(z:y)^2}{(z:y)^2} \cr
 &= \frac{(z:z)(y:y)}{(z:y)^2} - 1 \cr
\cr
d\phi &= \frac{2(z:dz)(y:y)}{(z:y)^2} - \frac{2(z:z)(y:y)(y:dz)}{(z:y)^3} \cr
 &= \frac{2(y:y)}{(z:y)^3}\,\Big((z:y)z-(z:z)y\Big):dz \cr
}$$
Note how this function is related to your function 
$$\eqalign{
 \phi &= f^2 &\implies d\phi=2f\,df \cr
}$$
Now substitute 
$$\eqalign{
 y &= Ma \cr
 z &= (b-t) &\implies dz=-dt \cr
}$$
to obtain
$$\eqalign{
df &= \frac{d\phi}{2f} \,\,= \frac{(y:y)}{(z:y)^3f}\,\Big((z:y)z-(z:z)y\Big):(-dt) \cr
\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} &= \frac{(y:y)}{(z:y)^3f}\,\Big((z:z)y-(z:y)z\Big) \cr\cr
}$$
A second set of substitutions
$$\eqalign{
 y &= (b-t) \cr
 z &= Ma &\implies dz=dM\,a\cr
}$$
yields
$$\eqalign{
df &= \frac{(y:y)}{(z:y)^3f}\,\Big((z:y)z-(z:z)y\Big):dM\,a \cr
   &= \frac{(y:y)}{(z:y)^3f}\,\Big((z:y)z-(z:z)y\Big)a^T:dM \cr
\frac{\partial f}{\partial M} &= \frac{(y:y)}{(z:y)^3f}\,\Big((z:y)z-(z:z)y\Big)a^T \cr\cr
}$$
Throughout the derivation, a colon was used to represent the inner product, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
a:b &= a\cdot b = a^Tb \cr
A:B &= {\rm tr}(A^TB) \cr
}$$
since it is easier to type, and it applies to matrices as well as vectors.